# A question about the supremum and infimum in a Banach lattice

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory, lattice-orders, vector-lattices

Given a **Banach lattice** $X$, it is well know that every finite subset $A$ of $X$ has a supremum and an infimum. 
For example, if $\{ x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ is a finite subset of $X$, then we have 
$$ sup (\{ x_1, \ldots, x_n\}) = \bigvee^n_{i=1} x_i \, \,,
\quad \text{and} \quad 
inf (\{ x_1, \ldots, x_n\}) = \bigwedge^n_{i=1} x_i \, \,.
$$

> Now we consider an **uncountable** subset $A = \{ a_i \colon i \in I \} \subset X$ (where $I$ is an index set). 
>   Also we assume that there is an element $\bar{a} \in X$ such that $a_i \leq \bar{a}$ for each $i \in I$ and there is an element $\underline{a} \in X$ such that $\underline{a} \leq a_i$ for each $i \in I$.
>
> I am curious that *under which kind of conditions*, the **existence** of a supremum and an infimum of the set $A$ can be guaranteed?

*Any idea or suggestions are really much appreciated! Thank you so much in advance!*

Answer (score 2):

The standard example of a Banach lattice is $C(K)$ for compact Hausdorff space $K$.  Typically, bounded infinite sets here might not have a supremum or infimum.  For example, if $s \in K$ is not isolated, $\{f \in C(K):\; f \ge 0, \; f(s) = 1\}$
has no infimum.

EDIT: Using the [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem), for any $t \ne s$ there is $f \in C(K)$ with
$f \ge 0$, $f(s)=1$ and $f(t)=0$.  Thus if an infimum $g$ existed, it would have to be 
$$ g(x) = \cases{1 & if $x=s$\cr 0 & otherwise}$$
But that's not continuous unless $\{s\}$ is open, i.e. $s$ is an isolated point.

Comment: Thanks for your counterexample, @Robert Israel . May I ask that under which kind of additional conditions, the existence of a supremum will be guaranteed? Would you mind to give me some hint or guidance please? Many thanks again :-)

Comment: Hi @Robert Israel , I am a bit struggling with understanding this counterexample and could not see why the set $\{ f \in C(K) \colon f\geq 0, f(s) = 1\}$ has no infimum. Would you mind explaining your counterexample in more detail please?  Thanks so much again :-)